# popup box in tablib in grails

Tags: grails, popup, taglib

how to create a custom yes or no alert popup box message in taglib,while deleting a row in grails.

This is my code.

```
          def submitDeleteButtonAttrs=['class':'delete', 'action':'delete','src':'../images/user_delete.png'
                                                ,'value':deleteLabel
                                                ,'formnovalidate':''
                                                ,'onclick':'return confirm('+deleteMessage+');' ]
    def deleteButton=g.actionSubmitImage(submitDeleteButtonAttrs);

    def searchTextHiddenFieldAttrs=['name':'searchText',
                                                'value':searchTextValue]    
    def searchTextHiddenField=g.hiddenField(searchTextHiddenFieldAttrs);

    def advSearchTextHiddenFieldAttrs=['name':'advancedSearchText',
        'value':advancedSearchTextValue];
    def advsearchTextHiddenField=g.hiddenField(advSearchTextHiddenFieldAttrs);

    def searchCriteriaHiddenFieldAttrs=['name':'searchCriteria',
        'value':searchCriteriaValue];
    def searchCriteriaHiddenField=g.hiddenField(searchCriteriaHiddenFieldAttrs);
    def operationAttrs=['name':'searchOperator','value':searchOperatorValue];
    def operationSelectHiddenField= g.hiddenField(operationAttrs);

         def uIDAttrs=['name':'id',
                'value':subscriberForUID[0]];
            def uidField=g.hiddenField(uIDAttrs);

          htmlOutput <<"""<td class="${innerClassName}"><form method="post">${uidField} ${searchTextHiddenField} ${advsearchTextHiddenField} ${deleteButton}</form></td>"""
```

here in this code the popup is not working properly.

Can any one help me where I done a mistake in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind, I would like to suggest using the modal of twitter bootstrap. Put the two buttons (cancel button, delete button) which will pass params to the controller upon clicking.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.But right now I want to go with the same what i am using.Can you help me how to create the popup without using the twitter plugin.